# Calculating transition probabilities

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm confused about a certain theory and I need some advice

789

456

123

This grid represents a basic house with 9 rooms.

A mouse, m, is in room i, and after a certain time interval, "t", it moves to an adjacent room, j. For example, the mouse can be in room 1, and after t, will either not move, or move to either room 2, or 4. Let's say it moved to room 2. After another "t" interval, it will either move to 1/3/5 or stay in 2. And so on. So it's a markov chain.

What method do I use to calculate the transition probabilities between each state where the rules above are all valid and the resulting probability of, after a long time, being in the bottom row (1/2/3) is 1/6, being in the middle 3 row (4/5/6) is 2/6 (1/3), and the top row (7/8/9) is 3/6 (1/2)?

Comment: You do not have information from the long term distribution about moving left or right, and only partial information about moving up or down.  But you can say that the transition probability of moving from the bottom to the middle row is double $\left(=\frac{1/3}{1/6}\right)$ the transition probability of moving from the middle row to the bottom row, while the transition probability of moving from the middle to the top row is $1.5  \left(=\frac{1/2}{1/3}\right)$ times the transition probability of moving from the top row to the middle row

Comment: Yeah, I figured that, but the current question on the assignment is the following, and that's all the information we are given :

Find transition probabilities between the cells such that the probability to be in the bottom row (cells 1,2,3) is 1/6. The probability to be in the middle row is 2/6. Represent the model as a Markov chain diagram (i.e. a directed graph) with the node labels corresponding to the cells numbers above.

I'm totally lost, I've tried doing the p(i->j) = 1/4( which is the probability of choosing to go left/right/up/down) * (πj / πi). I have calculated a number

Comment: of transition probabilities, but when running a large number of large-step simulations, the probabilities of each are:

Bottom row: 0.07239999622106552
Middle row: 0.2815999984741211
Top row: 0.6458999514579773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I said in comments that I thought you do not have information from the long term distribution about moving left or right, and only partial information about moving up or down. But you can say that the transition probability of moving from the bottom to the middle row is double the transition probability of moving from the middle row to the bottom row, while the transition probability of moving from the middle to the top row is $1.5$ times the transition probability of moving from the top row to the middle row

I am still not clear about the question, but let's suppose any answer meeting the condition will do, so then you could have for example

- $\Pr(1 \to 2)= \Pr(1 \to 4) = \Pr(2 \to 1)= \Pr(2\to 3)=\Pr (2 \to 5) = \Pr(3 \to 2)$ $=\Pr(3 \to 6) = 0.3$
- $\Pr(4 \to 1)= \Pr(4 \to 5) = \Pr(4 \to 7)= \Pr(5\to 2)=\Pr (5 \to 4) = \Pr(5 \to 6)$ $=\Pr(5 \to 8) =\Pr(6 \to 3) =\Pr(6 \to 5) =\Pr(6 \to 9) = 0.15$
- $\Pr(7 \to 4)= \Pr(7 \to 8) = \Pr(8 \to 5)= \Pr(8\to 7)=\Pr (8 \to 9) = \Pr(9 \to 6)$ $=\Pr(9 \to 8) = 0.1$

implying probabilities of no movement in a particular time step of

- $\Pr(1 \to 1) =  0.4$, $\Pr(2 \to 2) =  0.1$, $\Pr(3 \to 3) =  0.4$, $\Pr(4 \to 4) =  0.55$, $\Pr(5 \to 5) =  0.4$, $\Pr(6 \to 6) =  0.55$, $\Pr(7 \to 7) =  0.8$, $\Pr(8 \to 8) =  0.7$, $\Pr(9 \to 9) =  0.8$

If you simulate this with any starting position, I would expect that after say $100$ steps you would find the probability of each of the positions $1$ to $3$ having probability close to $\frac1{18}$, of each of the positions $4$ to $6$ having probability close to $\frac1{9}$, and of each of the positions $7$ to $9$ having probability close to $\frac1{6}$, adding up by row to $\frac16$, $\frac13$ and $\frac12$, which is what the question asked for

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm just wondering how you actually calculated those figures? I mean, I understand intuitively, but from a mathematics perspective, is there some sort of formula?

Comment: I just made them up so "the transition probability of moving from the bottom to the middle row is double the transition probability of moving from the middle row to the bottom row, while the transition probability of moving from the middle to the top row is 1.5 times the transition probability of moving from the top row to the middle row".  This is not a unique solution

Comment: So the transition probabilities (apart from staying) are in the order of a, 2a, and 3a. I do understand this (and the mathematical reasoning for that is quite simple, you would say, where b=bottom, m=middle, t=top Pbm = πm/πb * Pmb, but what I don't get is how you translated the knowledge of that to knowing that that is what the *outward* transitions are for all cells of that type (in other words what mathematical reasoning for that is). 

For example, one might assume that, for example, there would be a twice as likely chance from going from 1->4 as there is going from 1->2.

Comment: I think the pattern is actually $3a:\frac32 a : a$. The transition from $1\to 2$ seems to be largely irrelevant so I just made it the same as $1 \to 4$.  You can do this so long as all the transition probabilities from a state add up to $1$ or less, so in this case looking at state $2$ you have $3 \times 3a =9a \le 1$, so I made $a=0.1$.

Comment: Ah I see. Now going through it all by myself again makes it a lot more logical. Thank you very much, you've been a massive help!!